# Magento 2... installing sample data yields Area code not set error

Tags: magento2

I am fairly new to Magento in general, and been trying to install Magento 2 to get familiar with it.

I have successfully installed it, but the install I used did not come with sample data. So I followed these steps https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/sample-data-after-composer.html and now when I run the command `bin/magento setup:upgrade` I get the following error `Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session`.

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here is the complete dump after running the upgrade command:

`Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mag/generated/code/Composer
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mag/generated/code/Magento
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mag/generated/code/Symfony
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':
Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Directory':
Module 'Magento_Backend':
Module 'Magento_Theme':
Module 'Magento_Config':
Module 'Magento_Backup':
Module 'Magento_Eav':
Module 'Magento_Customer':
Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':
Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':
Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Module 'Magento_Cms':
Module 'Magento_Security':
Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Module 'Magento_Rule':
Module 'Magento_Msrp':
Module 'Magento_Search':
Module 'Magento_Bundle':
Module 'Magento_Quote':
Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_Widget':
Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
Module 'Magento_Payment':
Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_User':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
Module 'Magento_Sales':
Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
Module 'Magento_Contact':
Module 'Magento_Cookie':
Module 'Magento_Cron':
Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':
Module 'Magento_Checkout':
Module 'Magento_Integration':
Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':
Module 'Magento_SampleData':
Module 'Magento_Deploy':
Module 'Magento_Developer':
Module 'Magento_Dhl':
Module 'Magento_Authorization':
Module 'Magento_Tax':
Module 'Magento_ImportExport':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':
Module 'Magento_Weee':
Module 'Magento_Email':
Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':
Module 'Magento_Fedex':
Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_Ui':
Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':
Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':
Module 'Magento_CatalogSampleData':
Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Vault':
Module 'Magento_InstantPurchase':
Module 'Magento_Analytics':
Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':
Module 'Magento_Marketplace':
Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
Module 'Magento_MsrpSampleData':
Module 'Magento_Multishipping':
Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':
Module 'Magento_Newsletter':
Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':
Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':
Module 'Magento_PageCache':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales':
Module 'Magento_Paypal':
Module 'Magento_Persistent':
Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
Module 'Magento_DownloadableSampleData':
Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':
Module 'Magento_Captcha':
Module 'Magento_QuoteAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_ReleaseNotification':
Module 'Magento_Reports':
Module 'Magento_RequireJs':
Module 'Magento_Review':
Module 'Magento_ReviewAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_BundleSampleData':
Module 'Magento_Robots':
Module 'Magento_Rss':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':
Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':
Module 'Magento_SalesAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':
Module 'Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData':
Module 'Magento_CustomerSampleData':
Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':
Module 'Magento_ThemeSampleData':
Module 'Magento_ProductLinksSampleData':
Module 'Magento_CustomerAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_SendFriend':
Module 'Magento_Shipping':
Module 'Magento_Signifyd':
Module 'Magento_Sitemap':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleSampleData':
Module 'Magento_Swagger':
Module 'Magento_Swatches':
Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':
Module 'Magento_SwatchesSampleData':
Module 'Magento_ReviewSampleData':
Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':
Module 'Magento_TaxSampleData':
Module 'Magento_SalesRuleSampleData':
Module 'Magento_CmsSampleData':
Module 'Magento_Translation':
Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':
Module 'Magento_Ups':
Module 'Magento_SalesSampleData':
Module 'Magento_CatalogAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_Usps':
Module 'Magento_Variable':
Module 'Magento_Braintree':
Module 'Magento_Version':
Module 'Magento_Webapi':
Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':
Module 'Magento_GroupedProductSampleData':
Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':
Module 'Magento_WidgetSampleData':
Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
Module 'Magento_WishlistAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_WishlistSampleData':
Schema post-updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':
Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Directory':
Module 'Magento_Backend':
Module 'Magento_Theme':
Module 'Magento_Config':
Module 'Magento_Backup':
Module 'Magento_Eav':
Module 'Magento_Customer':
Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':
Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':
Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_Cms':
Module 'Magento_Security':
Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_Rule':
Module 'Magento_Msrp':
Module 'Magento_Search':
Module 'Magento_Bundle':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_Quote':
Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_Widget':
Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
Module 'Magento_Payment':
Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_User':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
Module 'Magento_Sales':
Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
Module 'Magento_Contact':
Module 'Magento_Cookie':
Module 'Magento_Cron':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':
Module 'Magento_Checkout':
Module 'Magento_Integration':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':
Module 'Magento_SampleData':
Module 'Magento_Deploy':
Module 'Magento_Developer':
Module 'Magento_Dhl':
Module 'Magento_Authorization':
Module 'Magento_Tax':
Module 'Magento_ImportExport':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':
Module 'Magento_Weee':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_Email':
Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':
Module 'Magento_Fedex':
Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_Ui':
Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':
Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':
Module 'Magento_CatalogSampleData':
Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Vault':
Module 'Magento_InstantPurchase':
Module 'Magento_Analytics':
Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':
Module 'Magento_Marketplace':
Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_MsrpSampleData':
Module 'Magento_Multishipping':
Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':
Module 'Magento_Newsletter':
Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':
Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':
Module 'Magento_PageCache':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales':
Module 'Magento_Paypal':
Module 'Magento_Persistent':
Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_DownloadableSampleData':
Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':
Module 'Magento_Captcha':
Module 'Magento_QuoteAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_ReleaseNotification':
Module 'Magento_Reports':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_RequireJs':
Module 'Magento_Review':
Module 'Magento_ReviewAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_BundleSampleData':
Module 'Magento_Robots':
Module 'Magento_Rss':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':
Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':
Module 'Magento_SalesAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':
Module 'Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData':
Module 'Magento_CustomerSampleData':
Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':
Module 'Magento_ThemeSampleData':
Module 'Magento_ProductLinksSampleData':
Module 'Magento_CustomerAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_SendFriend':
Module 'Magento_Shipping':
Module 'Magento_Signifyd':
Module 'Magento_Sitemap':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleSampleData':
Module 'Magento_Swagger':
Module 'Magento_Swatches':
Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':
Module 'Magento_SwatchesSampleData':
Module 'Magento_ReviewSampleData':
Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':
Module 'Magento_TaxSampleData':
Module 'Magento_SalesRuleSampleData':
Module 'Magento_CmsSampleData':
Module 'Magento_Translation':
Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':
Module 'Magento_Ups':
Module 'Magento_SalesSampleData':
Module 'Magento_CatalogAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_Usps':
Module 'Magento_Variable':
Module 'Magento_Braintree':
Module 'Magento_Version':
Module 'Magento_Webapi':
Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':
Module 'Magento_GroupedProductSampleData':
Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':
Module 'Magento_WidgetSampleData':
Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
Running schema recurring...
Module 'Magento_WishlistAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_WishlistSampleData':
Data install/update:
Module 'Magento_Store':
Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Directory':
Module 'Magento_Backend':
Module 'Magento_Theme':
Module 'Magento_Config':
Module 'Magento_Backup':
Module 'Magento_Eav':
Module 'Magento_Customer':
Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':
Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':
Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Module 'Magento_Cms':
Module 'Magento_Security':
Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Module 'Magento_Rule':
Module 'Magento_Msrp':
Module 'Magento_Search':
Module 'Magento_Bundle':
Module 'Magento_Quote':
Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_Widget':
Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
Module 'Magento_Payment':
Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':
Module 'Magento_User':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
Module 'Magento_Sales':
Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
Module 'Magento_Contact':
Module 'Magento_Cookie':
Module 'Magento_Cron':
Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':
Module 'Magento_Checkout':
Module 'Magento_Integration':
Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':
Module 'Magento_SampleData':
Module 'Magento_Deploy':
Module 'Magento_Developer':
Module 'Magento_Dhl':
Module 'Magento_Authorization':
Module 'Magento_Tax':
Module 'Magento_ImportExport':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':
Module 'Magento_Weee':
Module 'Magento_Email':
Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':
Module 'Magento_Fedex':
Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':
Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_Ui':
Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':
Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':
Module 'Magento_CatalogSampleData':
Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_Vault':
Module 'Magento_InstantPurchase':
Module 'Magento_Analytics':
Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':
Module 'Magento_Marketplace':
Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
Module 'Magento_MsrpSampleData':
Module 'Magento_Multishipping':
Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':
Module 'Magento_Newsletter':
Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':
Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':
Module 'Magento_PageCache':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProductSales':
Module 'Magento_Paypal':
Module 'Magento_Persistent':
Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
Module 'Magento_DownloadableSampleData':
Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':
Module 'Magento_Captcha':
Module 'Magento_QuoteAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_ReleaseNotification':
Module 'Magento_Reports':
Module 'Magento_RequireJs':
Module 'Magento_Review':
Module 'Magento_ReviewAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_BundleSampleData':
Module 'Magento_Robots':
Module 'Magento_Rss':
Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':
Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':
Module 'Magento_SalesAnalytics':
Module 'Magento_SalesInventory':
Module 'Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData':
Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData':
Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.`

**EDIT:**
I should mention that on the browser I get the following:
`Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory.`

Comment: which Magento 2 version you are using?  I mean Magento 2.0/2.1/2.2?

Comment: @kunj the latest - 2.2.6-dev

Comment: Try after clear `generated` and `cache`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

Run this command first:

```
php bin/magento sampledata:reset
```

Then run again:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

If you face memory exhausted error then try this:

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you... Increasing MAMP's php memory and then running these 2 commands, fixed the issue. Much appreciated Kunj.

Comment: Kunj, on a side note, do you have any good resources on how to create a custom theme, and also general modifications to Magento 2? I' totally out of element with M2.

Comment: Welcome, happy to help you!!, You can learn how to create the custom theme from here: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-custom-theme-magento-2-part-1/. For other things, you can go with this: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html